# Do >2-state cellular automata exist?

Tags: procedural-generation

I'm trying to implement a zone system into my game that randomly sets chunks (the cells) to a certain value from a list and that would effect nearby chunks. It's basically a cellular automaton in which instead of the cells being on/off, they would have multiple options, like red/green/blue/yellow/brown or such.

Do this kind of cellular automata exist?

Comment: According to wikipedia: _A cellular automaton consists of a regular grid of cells, each in one of a finite number of states, such as on and off (in contrast to a [coupled map lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupled_map_lattice))._

Answer (score 3):

Yes: [wireworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireworld) has 4 states, for example.

The on/off was created in a quest for the simplest Turing complete model of an automaton, but there is no reason for you to also be limited to 2 states. (Neither is there a reason for the kernel (transition function inputs) to be limited to just the direct neighbours.)